# Deadlock in SQLServer using Java + JDBC, but not when executing same commands in SSMS

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, database-deadlocks

I am troubleshooting a web application built in Java that has a module to replicate data between different servers, which is experiencing deadlocks in SQLServer when using anything more than a single thread to process incoming changes. The deadlock graph generated by SQLServer is of no help because it seems to imply that locks are being added on indexes that are not even involved in the query that is deadlocking.

What is even more perplexing is that I cannot reproduce this at all manually by executing commands in SSMS in two separate transactions -- the correct indexes and rows are locked, and no deadlock occurs. However, I have been able to create a basic java application that will reproduce the problem almost 100% of the time. It happens on SQLServer 2012, 2016, and 2019. I haven't tried any others.

Consider the following database tables and code:

### Schema:

```
create table entities
(
    uuid          varchar(100) not null,
    entity_type   varchar(100) not null,
    internal_id   varchar(255) null,
    date_modified datetime2(6) not null,
    head_rev_id   varchar(100) null,
    constraint entities_pk primary key clustered (uuid)
)
go

create unique nonclustered index entities_uidx on entities (entity_type, internal_id) where (internal_id is not null)
go

create table revisions
(
    entity_id   varchar(100)   not null,
    uuid        varchar(100)   not null,
    parent_uuid varchar(100)   null,
    priority    numeric(20, 0) not null,
    state       varchar(50)    not null,
    constraint revisions_pk primary key clustered (uuid)
)
go

create nonclustered index revisions_parent_idx on revisions (parent_uuid)
go

create nonclustered index revisions_entity_idx on revisions (entity_id)
go

create unique nonclustered index u_duplicate_unassigned on revisions (entity_id, state) where (state = 'UNASSIGNED')
go
```

### Java Application:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Thread t1 = new Thread(new DeadlockTest("f965ae06-d3ad-44cb-b7c3-607833b2bf28", "b5b1e3de-5341-4afc-b180-6d91b2e857cb"));
    Thread t2 = new Thread(new DeadlockTest("f5f5142f-7f9a-4efb-91c4-6364d9967dd4", "e2e7583b-29c9-4a86-8c2c-b078e9d6ab64"));

    t1.start();
    t2.start();

    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    System.err.println();
    System.exit(0);
}

private static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
    return DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.2.19:1433;databaseName=deadlock_test");
}

private static class DeadlockTest implements Runnable {
    String entityId;
    String revisionId;

    public DeadlockTest(String entityId, String revisionId) {
        this.entityId = entityId;
        this.revisionId = revisionId;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try (Connection conn = getConnection()) {
            conn.setAutoCommit(false);

            final String SQL_INSERT_ENTITY = "" +
                    "INSERT INTO entities (\n" +
                    "  uuid,\n" +
                    "  entity_type,\n" +
                    "  internal_id,\n" +
                    "  date_modified) VALUES (\n" +
                    "  ?,\n" +
                    "  ?,\n" +
                    "  ?,\n" +
                    "  getdate()\n" +
                    ")";

            try (PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(SQL_INSERT_ENTITY)) {
                ps.setString(1, entityId);
                ps.setString(2, "FOLDER");
                ps.setNull(3, Types.VARCHAR);
                ps.executeUpdate();
            }

            Thread.sleep((long) (Math.random() * 1000));

            String insertRevisionSql = "" +
                    "insert into revisions (entity_id, uuid, parent_uuid, priority, state)\n" +
                    "select ?, ?, ?, ?, ?\n";

            try (PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(insertRevisionSql)) {
                ps.setString(1, entityId);
                ps.setString(2, revisionId);
                ps.setNull(3, Types.VARCHAR);

                ps.setNull(3, Types.VARCHAR);

                ps.setLong(4, System.currentTimeMillis());

                ps.setString(5, "APPLIED");

                ps.executeUpdate();
            }

            Thread.sleep((long) (Math.random() * 1000));

            try (PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE r SET r.state = ? from revisions r with(index(revisions_pk)) WHERE uuid = ?")) {
                ps.setString(1, "APPLIED");
                ps.setString(2, revisionId);

                ps.executeUpdate();
            }
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever I check the database locks before the deadlock victim is chosen, I see the following. (I used the following query:)

```
SELECT dm_tran_locks.request_session_id,
       dm_tran_locks.resource_database_id,
       CASE
           WHEN resource_type = 'object'
               THEN OBJECT_NAME(dm_tran_locks.resource_associated_entity_id)
           ELSE OBJECT_NAME(partitions.OBJECT_ID)
           END                                     AS ObjectName,
       partitions.index_id,
       indexes.name                                AS index_name,
       dm_tran_locks.resource_type,
       dm_tran_locks.resource_description,
       dm_tran_locks.resource_associated_entity_id,
       dm_tran_locks.request_mode,
       dm_tran_locks.request_status,
       cleanlockrs
FROM sys.dm_tran_locks
         LEFT JOIN sys.partitions ON partitions.hobt_id = dm_tran_locks.resource_associated_entity_id
         JOIN sys.indexes ON indexes.OBJECT_ID = partitions.OBJECT_ID AND indexes.index_id = partitions.index_id
         CROSS APPLY(
    SELECT LEFT(SUBSTRING(resource_description, 2, LEN(resource_description)), LEN(resource_description) - 2)
) clean(cleanlockrs)
WHERE resource_associated_entity_id > 0
  AND resource_database_id = DB_ID()
  and resource_type = 'KEY'
ORDER BY request_session_id, resource_associated_entity_id
```

Notice that session 64 is requesting an Update lock on the primary key of the revision that was created in session 65, and likewise in the other direction. Why is this happening when I do this in JDBC but not when I execute the same statements in SSMS in two transactions? Is this a problem with the JDBC driver? From what I read, the JDBC driver is supposed to correctly handle row-locking. **We are using the jdbc 4.1 driver**

[image]

Here's the deadlock report if it will be of any use.

```
<deadlock>
 <victim-list>
  <victimProcess id="processe21456ca8" />
 </victim-list>
 <process-list>
  <process id="processe21456ca8" taskpriority="0" logused="900" waitresource="KEY: 6:72057594209566720 (5ba4cb91ab7b)" waittime="3778" ownerId="7883458" transactionname="implicit_transaction" lasttranstarted="2020-02-04T22:33:06.343" XDES="0xdfa7b0428" lockMode="U" schedulerid="1" kpid="565588" status="suspended" spid="65" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2020-02-04T22:33:26.620" lastbatchcompleted="2020-02-04T22:33:06.790" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.790" clientapp="Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server" hostname="kefla" hostpid="0" loginname="dbuser" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="7883458" currentdb="6" currentdbname="DEADLOCK_TEST" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128058">
   <executionStack>
    <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="78" stmtend="248" sqlhandle="0x020000000a12f02ff1a3c9c207fe1acc2226bbe573617d6c0000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
    <frame procname="unknown" line="1" sqlhandle="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
   </executionStack>
   <inputbuf>
(@P0 nvarchar(4000),@P1 nvarchar(4000))UPDATE r SET r.state = @P0 from revisions r with(index(revisions_pk)) WHERE uuid = @P1                   </inputbuf>
  </process>
  <process id="processe21457088" taskpriority="0" logused="900" waitresource="KEY: 6:72057594209566720 (aac0822c1596)" waittime="3779" ownerId="7883459" transactionname="implicit_transaction" lasttranstarted="2020-02-04T22:33:06.343" XDES="0xdda4f8428" lockMode="U" schedulerid="1" kpid="640" status="suspended" spid="64" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2020-02-04T22:33:26.620" lastbatchcompleted="2020-02-04T22:33:06.557" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.557" clientapp="Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server" hostname="kefla" hostpid="0" loginname="dbuser" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="7883459" currentdb="6" currentdbname="DEADLOCK_TEST" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128058">
   <executionStack>
    <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="78" stmtend="248" sqlhandle="0x020000000a12f02ff1a3c9c207fe1acc2226bbe573617d6c0000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
    <frame procname="unknown" line="1" sqlhandle="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
   </executionStack>
   <inputbuf>
(@P0 nvarchar(4000),@P1 nvarchar(4000))UPDATE r SET r.state = @P0 from revisions r with(index(revisions_pk)) WHERE uuid = @P1                   </inputbuf>
  </process>
 </process-list>
 <resource-list>
  <keylock hobtid="72057594209566720" dbid="6" objectname="DEADLOCK_TEST.dbo.revisions" indexname="revisions_pk" id="locke02205780" mode="X" associatedObjectId="72057594209566720">
   <owner-list>
    <owner id="processe21457088" mode="X" />
   </owner-list>
   <waiter-list>
    <waiter id="processe21456ca8" mode="U" requestType="wait" />
   </waiter-list>
  </keylock>
  <keylock hobtid="72057594209566720" dbid="6" objectname="DEADLOCK_TEST.dbo.revisions" indexname="revisions_pk" id="lockdfb54d680" mode="X" associatedObjectId="72057594209566720">
   <owner-list>
    <owner id="processe21456ca8" mode="X" />
   </owner-list>
   <waiter-list>
    <waiter id="processe21457088" mode="U" requestType="wait" />
   </waiter-list>
  </keylock>
 </resource-list>
</deadlock>
```

Comment: As you have autocommit turned off - where do you expect the commit to happen?

Comment: The commit doesn’t happen in this example for the sake of demonstrating the issue. But in reality it will commit at the end of method. There is a lot of unnecessary details left out. It won’t even make it to the commit anyhow.